# Which horror film has this basement?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember a few years ago watching a horror film. I think a family of the mum and 2 sons had just moved in.

There was a trapdoor in the garage (I think) that was nailed down and they were told not to ever open it. But the younger boy did. It's really deep and I remember the older boy dropping something down and he counted how long it fell for and the object eventually hit water. I think they also put a torch down connected to a string but this got torn off? I think at the bottom of this hole were some sort of monsters?

Does anyone know what film this is?

Comment: Were there any sci-fi or fantasy elements in this film?  Not all horror is on-topic.

Comment: @jwodder edited the question :)

Comment: Reminds me of Joe Dante's film, The Hole, from 2009. Two brothers who move into their new house in Bensenville with their single mother, find a locked trapdoor in the basement. The trailer shows them tying a torch to a rope and dropping it down. The hole is supposed to be bottomless though, and each persons fears crawl out of it, so a variety of monsters. Don't recall water encountered but do remember enjoying it. So, a partial fit... ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps, The Hole, a 2009 film by Joe Dante.

Two brothers who move into their new house in Bensenville with their single mother, find a locked trapdoor in the basement. The trailer shows them using a torch in the hole, but instead they drop stuff in to it to see how deep. The hole is supposed to be bottomless though, and each persons fears crawl out of it, so a variety of monsters. Don't recall water encountered but do remember enjoying it. So, a partial fit..

Trailer:

Long time since I saw this, but I do enjoy Dante's movies.

Comment: Yes - this was it! Thanks a lot!!!